# MAGENTO - Specific characters (Thai Alphabet) are not always displayed properly

Tags: magento-1.9, internationalization, character-encoding

I am faced to a problem I can't undertand and can't fix.
My website, an online supermarket develo) has two different languages English and Thai 
Products name are in both language and we've also start to translate all english descritpion in Thai. Then the problem appears:

- On the Product page in Thai view, everything is fine http://delishop.co.th/home/groceries/pasta-dry-food/couscous-epices/
- But When we navigate in a category in grid view the Thai characters are not displayed well : http://delishop.co.th/home/groceries/pasta-dry-food/?___from_store=default&___store=thai&mode=list

In the DB all characters are properly displayed.
Do you know what I should do to fix this problem ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check to make sure your database tables are using `UTF8`, and try to use the out-of-box template to see if the problem persists, if it doesn't then you'll know its something to do with your design `phtml` files.

Comment: I see he problem is only with product descriptions. Please share the code you are using to display description in your category pages.